# How to set dynamic value on extraParams store extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

hi i have a problem to store dynamic value to `extraParams` on extjs..

my case is i can get value from my component when im `console` it on here:

```
listeners: {
    load: function (store, records, success) {
        console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[reference=terminal2]')[0])
    }
}
```

i got the value from that component, but when i try to pass it to `extraParam` i got error `undefined`..

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: Config.getApi() + 'api/public/index',
    extraParams: {
        dParams: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[reference=terminal2]')[0]
    },
},
```

i got error `undefined`..

my full store code

```
Ext.define('Admin.store.npk.mdm.LayananAlat', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.layananalat',

    requires: [
        'Config'
    ],

    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: Config.getApi() + 'api/public/index',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        paramsAsJson: true,
        timeout: 120000,
        extraParams: {
            dParams: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[reference=terminal2]')[0]
        },
        headers: {
            'token': Ext.util.Cookies.get('Tokens')
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: function (obj) {
                return obj.result
            },
            totalProperty: function (obj) {
                return obj.count
            }
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function (store, records, success) {
            console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[reference=terminal2]')[0])
        }
    }
});
```

or is there another way to passing dynamic value to `extraParams` on `proxy` store in extjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy settings will be set at construction stage when most likely your UI is not build so your component query can not return the referenced UI element.

Turn off `autoLoad` and remove the proxy part from the store definition. Then set the proxy somewhere you can be sure the UI is already constructed. E.g. on the view's show/painted event you can add a code like

```js
   const store = Ext.getStore('layananalat');
   store.setProxy({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: Config.getApi() + 'api/public/index',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        paramsAsJson: true,
        timeout: 120000,
        extraParams: {
            dParams: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[reference=terminal2]')[0]
        },
        headers: {
            'token': Ext.util.Cookies.get('Tokens')
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: function (obj) {
                return obj.result
            },
            totalProperty: function (obj) {
                return obj.count
            }
   });
   store.load();
```